# Building JSON object using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to create a JSON array using JQuery (from an existing JSON object $yAxis) as per the below lines of code.

```
abc.yAxis = [   
    $.each($yAxis, function(i, obj){
        var $metric= obj.title.text;
        var $oppositeAxis=obj.title.opposite;
        { title: {
            style: {
                font: 'xyz',
                color: 'black'
            },
            text:'$metric'.substring(0,30),
        }, 
        opposite: $oppositeAxis
    },              
}); 
];
```

FireBug always says the below error:

```
[SyntaxError: invalid label
[at]
color: 'black']
```

My existing JSON object ($yAxis) is:

```
{
"yaxis": "[{'title':{'text':'A'},'opposite':false},{'title':{'text':'B'},'opposite':true},    {'title':{'text':'C'},'opposite':false}]"
}
```

I will be sending this new JSON as input to highCharts.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Seems like you want to create an object. I recommend to read the [MDN documentation about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?red) (especially about [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?red#Using_object_initializers)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the array `abc.yAxis = [...];`, Javascript is expecting to find a list of values, or name-value pairs which will form the content of your array.. so finding

```
$.each($yAxis, function(i, obj){ ... }); // semi colon is invalid here (Thanks @FelixKling)
```

Is really not a valid label - which is what causes your error..

You will have to do it like this:

```
abc.yAxis = []; // define the array, you can also use "new Array()"

$.each($yAxis, function(i, obj){ // for each $yAxis
    var $metric= obj.title.text;
    var $oppositeAxis=obj.title.opposite;

    // Now we push the wanted object into the array
    abc.yAxis.push({ title: { 
        style: {
            font: 'xyz',
            color: 'black'
        },
        text:'$metric'.substring(0,30),
    }, 
        opposite: $oppositeAxis
    });              
});
```

Note that this creates an array of objects. I hope that what you tried to achieve..

You can read about objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), and about Array.push() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: The explanation  is not correct. `$.each($yAxis, function(i, obj){ ...});` is *valid* there (well, the trailing `;` is not valid). `$.each` is just a function that gets called and the *return value* (which is `undefined` I assume), becomes the element in the array. It's like `var foo = [bar()];`. The error comes from somewhere in `{ title: { style: {` because it is interpreted as a block, not as an object literal.

Comment: I actually didn't know that. Thanks @FelixKling. However my solution will work as well right?

Comment: Yes, the solution is fine!